# Database is not changing after a migration

Tags: django, django-south

So using south, I wanted to add a new field is_private to one of my models.

Following the tutorial, after changing the models.py file, I should do this:

```
./manage.py schemamigration reconstructions --auto
```

which returns:

```
 Added field is_private on reconstructions.Reconstruction
Created 0005_auto__add_field_reconstruction_is_private.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate reconstructions
```

Which is great. Now next step is,

```
python manage.py migrate reconstructions
```

And that prints:

```
- Migrating forwards to 0005_auto__add_field_reconstruction_is_private.
 > reconstructions:0005_auto__add_field_reconstruction_is_private
 - Loading initial data for reconstructions.
No fixtures found.
```

it seems to be doing it's job. But when I afterwards check the field is_private, Django throws me an error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'is_private' into field.
```

Which tells me south did not changed the database at all. Why is so?

Extra information:
The model class:

```
class Reconstruction(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=36, primary_key=True,
                          editable=False)

    uploader = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.TextField(blank=True)
    viewcount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    error_flag = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    last_modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_private = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

The code causing the crash:

```
recordings = Recording.objects.filter(is_done=True).filter(is_private=False).order_by('-create_date')
```

Comment: Error indicates migration is still to run. Run this in shell `python manage.py migrate --list` to check the status of your migration.

Comment: That error doesn't indicate a database issue at all.  That's an error purely at the class level. Please post the model code, the code causing the error, and the traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have attached the information you have asked. I thought it seemed to indicate it cannot find the is_private column.

Comment: @Ahsan You might be right since this is what it gives me  
    reconstructions
      (*) 0001_initial
      (*) 0002_auto__del_field_reconstruction_is_private
      (*) 0003_auto__add_field_reconstruction_is_private
      
however, why is it not running these migrations? I told it to migrate a million times?  

python manage.py migrate reconstructions  

gives me :<br/>


Running migrations for reconstructions:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for reconstructions.
No fixtures found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observation: you added `is_private` to `Reconstruction`, but you're trying to filter `Recording` objects based on that property. Perhaps this is the issue?